# object with displacement map looks low poly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, displacement, bump

I have a beach scene here and when rendering in cycles, the sand at the front looks very low-poly even with smooth shading. I turned off the displacement map but that also took away the bumps in the sand. the plane has a lot of geometry and it looks fine in material preview and Eevee. what am I doing wrong?

all textures are packed

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPTQKa7Fv9lGHx73c0n52zlck0AgSkcw/view?usp=sharing)

[image: eevee]
[image: cycles viewport]
[image: scene basics]
[image: bad sand render]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you simply have too little geometry on that plane. That it looks better in Eevee seems to have to do with how shadows are being handled: there is far less contrast, so it's harder to tell if the vertices are low-poly.
**Try increasing the amount of subdivisions of the beach.**